# Double Eval- Repeating Value

Tags: 2010, infopath, xpath

I'm having some trouble with a double-eval concatenation.  I am using the formula `xdMath:Eval(xdMath:Eval(xdXDocument:GetDOM("REST Vacation")/ns1:feed/ns1:entry, 'concat(//d:EmployeeID, ";")'),"..")`, and it is ALMOST working.  The problem is that while I get the proper number of output values, they are all the first value of the list (i.e. if my list were { 15, 32, 46, 71, 42 }, I would get back "15;15;15;15;15;").  Has anyone had this problem?  I think it has to do with the ".." in the outer eval() function, but I have tried things like "../.." and get no results at all.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out- just had to add a "." in front of //d:EmployeeID and it started working properly.

IE.

```
eval(eval(DisplayName, 'concat(.,"; ")'), "..")
```